# angular contenteditable and highlight directives don't play nicely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, contenteditable

I'm trying to highlight matched text (using ngModel $formatters and $parsers) in a contenteditable div. Highlighting doesn't happen after render, and listening for ngModel changes to update the HTML moves the caret with each change.

I.e., typing 'search' should convert to (SEARCH) after it is typed in the $viewValue and remain 'search' (or SEARCH in this example) in the $modelValue, and remove parentheses if you delete the 'h' off 'search'

**EDIT** I edited the plunkr so that there are now two fields tied to the same model (one input, one contenteditable pre, but it doesn't really matter) -- when you make changes in one, the other picks up the $modelValue change and pushes it through $formatters, but the div in which changes were made does not pick up the change. I would like it so that all divs (whether there is one or several) $parse and $format the $viewValue when it changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/H4Cw5t?p=preview

HTML

```
<pre ng-model="someString" highlight-search contenteditable="true"></pre>
```

JS

```
app.directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      if(!ctrl) return;

      // view -> model
      element.bind('keyup', function() {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        if (key === 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)) return;

        var value = element.html();

        if (ctrl.$modelValue !== value) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
            });
            //element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);   //messes up cursor position
        }

        console.log(ctrl.$modelValue, '\n', ctrl.$viewValue);
      });

      // model -> view
      ctrl.$render = function() {
        element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('highlightSearch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var highlightSites = function (input) {
                return input.replace(/search/gi, '(SEARCH)');
            };

            var unhighlightSites = function (input) {
                return input.replace(/[^A-Z ]/ig, '');
            };

            ngModel.$parsers.push(unhighlightSites);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(highlightSites);
        }
    }
});
```